# How to get timestamp of http response using curl

Tags: curl, http-headers

I am using curl to hit a server through an http post request and sending xml as request body, using the following piece of code :

`curl -X POST -d @path to xml file URL`

`Ex: curl -X POST -d @C:\docs\test.xml http://www.example.com`

which successfully returns the json http response as follows :

```
"header": {
    "product": "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "version": "xxxxxxxx"
},
"status": {
    "elapsedTime": 329,
    "httpReturnCode": 200,
    "statusCode": 0,
    "success": true,
    "startTime": 1350387905444,
    "statusDescription": "Successful"
},
```

But this json response doesn't show the endTime timestamp, the time at which the webservice call returns.

I know a way from curl to find out the response time of a url, using command :

`curl -o /dev/null -w "Connect: %{time_connect} TTFB: %{time_starttransfer} Total time: %{time_total} n" http://www.google.com`

The above command returns the response time in terms of milliseconds. Is there any way we can get the timestamp of http response using curl ? My requirement is to hit the server using http POST with a request body(XML file) and then get it response time in terms of timestamp. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think the server should include this timestamp in the JSON it returns?

Comment: @Tichodroma, honestly I do not ve much knowledge about this Json stuff, what it returns and not, but getting the timestamp when the response returns is part of my requirement. Please enlighten me if you have much ideas about this stuff and it will be great if I get to know the answer to above question :)

Comment: Why don't you use a wrapper approach like in your last `curl` example?

Comment: Tried it. It returns the response time in terms of milli seconds, I want the response in terms of timestamp. Looking into further options.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to include the time curl is called by environment variable. Then you can calculate the absolute times of your response times afterwards.

In windows this would be

```
curl.exe -o NUL -w "Time: %TIME% Connect: %{time_connect} TTFB: %{time_starttransfer} Total time: %{time_total}\n" http://www.google.com
```